# Cant get video element in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, video, polymer

I have tried for hours and even went to googles page 2 for answers, but I just can't fin a solution that works. I know there are other questions about this and believe me, I have checked them all, but no one works. 10 of those are commented out in the script.

> What I'm trying to do is change the speed of a video, the options are 2.0, 1.0 and 0.5 speed. When either one of those is chosen the function in 'onclick' is started. But I need the video element to change the playbackrate. All help is  appreciated :)

```
<dom-module id="my-video">
 <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
        :host {
            display: block;

            padding: 10px;
        }

       /* Styles... */

    </style>

    <!-- If videoData.mime exists -->
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isEmpty(videoData.mime)}}">
       <video id="videoPlayer" onclick="Kuk(this)" poster="{{getThubnail(videoData.thumbnail)}}" controls>
           <source src="uploadedFiles/{{videoData.userid}}/{{videoData.id}}.mp4" type="{{videoData.mime}}">
           <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="">
       </video>
       <div id="subtitles"></div>
     </template>

     <!-- If videoData.mime doesn't exists -->
     <template is="dom-if" if="{{isEmpty(videoData.mime)}}">
        <video id="videoPlayer" poster="{{getThubnail(videoData.thumbnail)}}" controls>
           <source src="videos/subtitle-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
           <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="/subtitles/subtitles0.vtt">
         </video>
     </template>

            <!-- SPEED CONTROLS source: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ufct35ys5t -->
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="toggle_radio">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="{{speed_dobble}}" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="{{speed_normal}}" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" name="toggle_option">
                    <input type="radio" onclick="{{speed_half}}" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle" name="toggle_option">
                    <label for="first_toggle">
                        <p class="other-title tri_toggle">2.0</p>
                    </label>
                    <label for="second_toggle">
                        <p class="other-title tri_toggle">1.0</p>
                    </label>
                    <label for="third_toggle">
                        <p class="other-title tri_toggle">0.5</p>
                    </label>
                    <div class="toggle_option_slider">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</template>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
    class MyVideo extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'my-video';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                URL: {
                    type: String,
                    value: '/api/video.php?id='
                }
                /* some values */

            };
        }

       /*Some code...*/

        speed_dobble() {
            console.log("Speed Dobble");

            // var player = this.elementShadow.querySelector('#videoPlayer');  // <-- 1  Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
            // var player = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('video');            // <-- 2  Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
            // var player = $('#videoPlayer');                                 // <-- 3  $ is not defined
            // var player = $(this.$.videoPlayer);                             // <-- 4  $ is not defined
            // var player = this.$$('#videoPlayer');                           // <-- 5  Not a function
            // var player = this.$.videoPlayer.querySelector('video');         // <-- 6  Undefined
            // var player = this.$.videoPlayer;                                // <-- 7  Undefined
            // var player = this.$$['#videoPlayer'];                           // <-- 8  Undefined
            // var player = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#video");    // <-- 9  null
            // var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');            // <-- 10 null

            console.log(player);
        }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyVideo.is, MyVideo);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure either videoPlayer is being created at runtime? Also just to simplify things, have you tried omitting the MIME type altogether thereby removing the dom-if - according to [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4281) the MIME type is optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cuttsy27 already said, in Polymer you usually attach events in a declarative way by using the `on-` prefix + the name of the event, so the attribute name should be `on-click`. Also, as seen in his example, but not mentioned, you need to provide the callback name as a string. "**speed_double**", for example, is not a *data binding*, so you don't need the curly braces.

So, for example, this:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="{{speed_dobble}}" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
```

Should become

```
<input type="radio" on-click="speed_dobble" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
```

Also, another reason I added a new answer, instead of just a comment is that the `this.$.videoPlayer` "*shortcut*" to get the element by ID might not work in fact. And that's because under `this.$` you will find the elements that are available as soon as the element is included. So you won't find there elements that are added conditionally, since your element is in a `dom-if`. So you might want to try to query by using something like

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById('videoPlayer')
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to set a value attribute to each of the input fields and on-click call a single function like 'changeSpeed'. you can pass the event to the function to get the clicked item's value and set that value as your video's speed attribute.

this.$.videoPlayer should be the correct selector in this instance, I believe.

Also, try using `on-click=""` rather than `onclick=""`.

I would try something like:

`<input type="radio" value="1.0" on-click="changeSpeed" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
   <input type="radio" value="0.5" on-click="changeSpeed" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" name="toggle_option">
   <input type="radio" value="2.0" on-click="changeSpeed" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle" name="toggle_option">`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it worked fine for me (Polymer 2) where v is the id of my `video` element.

```
      this.$.v.pause();
      this.$.v.load();
      this.$.v.playbackRate = 2;
```

To expand on that, I would create an videospeed property in your element with an observer that calls a function to change the current playback speed based on my example.

If you still can't make a reference to your videoPlayer, then there could possibly be an issue with you having two items with the same id (yeah, I know DOM-IF should only ever create one of them, but just a guess).